# Shutting down sockets properly

Tags: python, sockets

I'm trying to make a server / client connection with sockets. But they will not close properly and I can't wrap my head around why.

#### Update 1

I've corrected my stupid misstake below of not actually CALLING the s.close function in the question.
But it turn out this was'nt my problem.

#### End of updates

This is my server code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import socket
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Server connection
    s = socket.socket()          # Create a socket object
    host = socket.gethostname()  # Get local machine name
    port = 12345                 # Reserve a port for your service.

    print 'Server started!'
    print 'Waiting for clients...'

    s.bind((host, port))        # Bind to the port
    s.listen(5)                 # Now wait for client connection.
    c, addr = s.accept()     # Establish connection with client.
    print 'Got connection from', addr
    msg = c.recv(1024)

    print addr, ' >> ', msg

    if msg == 'close':
        print 'Closing down'
        c.send('SENT: Closing down')

    c.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
    c.close()
```

This is my client code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import socket

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Server
    s = socket.socket()          # Create a socket object
    host = socket.gethostname()  # Get local machine name
    port = 12345                 # Reserve a port for your service.

    print 'Connecting to ', host, port
    s.connect((host, port))

    msg = raw_input('CLIENT >> ')
    s.send(msg)
    msg = s.recv(1024)
    print 'SERVER >> ', msg

    s.close()                     # Close the socket when done
```

And this is the error message it produces:

```
In [13]: %run cjboxd.py
Server started!
Waiting for clients...
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/utils/py3compat.pyc in execfile(fname, *where)
    173             else:
    174                 filename = fname
--> 175             __builtin__.execfile(filename, *where)

/home/nine/slask/cjboxd.py in <module>()
     19     print 'Waiting for clients...'
     20 
---> 21     s.bind((host, port))        # Bind to the port
     22     s.listen(5)                 # Now wait for client connection.
     23     c, addr = s.accept()     # Establish connection with client.

/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.pyc in meth(name, self, *args)
    222 
    223 def meth(name,self,*args):
--> 224     return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
    225 
    226 for _m in _socketmethods:

error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

It will work like a minute later.

Comment: What other program binds to port 12345?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you need `socket.socket.setsockopt`, .i.e `s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)`

Though the socket will be closed by the os when process ended, it is a good behavior to call close() explicitly. 
However, after that, the local addr(local_ip, local_port) is not avaiable until 2 `MSL(maximum segment lifetime)` has passed. Why? and what we can do? you can read these:

http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_TCPConnectionTermination-3.htm
and http://www.unixguide.net/network/socketfaq/4.5.shtml

It will be difficult to me to post it more clear than they do :).

Comment: Huh? What are you talking about

Comment: @JakobBowyer the problem is caused by the socket state TIME_WAIT, when the server program exit, the socket is closed but the port is not freed, so the bind operation can not be done.

Comment: Or you just, idk close the socket? Let python handle the cleaning up with the operating system

Comment: @JakobBowyer, well I didn't see the `s.close`, but I believe that the problem talking about here is that when the server restarts, it may fail to bind the port with error messge `error: [Errno 98] Address already in use`.

Comment: Yes because the socket was never cleaned up by the interpreter

Comment: @JakobBowyer, no, I meant when after the server program exited, though the socket is closed, it would be still busy until 2 MSL passed

Comment: @Marcus you should add some of the explanation from the link into your main answer. A while ago I was also bitten by the OS not closing the sockets.

Comment: @HansThen, a little improvement.. sorry that I am not a native English speaker. :)

Comment: @HansThen You were bitten by the OS not releasing the *port*. The socket was closed when you closed it.

Answer (score 8):

```
s.close                     # Close the socket when done
```

Sticks out to my eyes because you don't actually CALL anything, you should try `s.close()`

Comment: Ok. Now it's official. I'm blind! ;)

Comment: ;) I once tried to work out why my `class` wasn't working then I realized I wrote `def`

Comment: I did'nt work anyway. But I'm thankful that you catched this stupid misstake of mine. But I do belive Marcus has an explaination for my problem. Anyway +1

Answer (score 3):

you are calling `s.close`, instead of `s.close()`.

you need to invoke the socket.close() method if you want the client to terminate the connection.`